# Whats the difference between spinning skulls, stars, and birds when you get dizzy?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

In Street Fighter you have either spinning skulls, stars or birds when you get dizzy.

Is the animation random, does it rely on certain conditions which you get and are there any side effects?

I have read the following explanations, but neither is "certain":

- It is totally random which animation you get
- The animation depends on the overflow of the stun points. e.g. Stun required 900, 900-910 = stars, 911-920 birds, 921-? skulls.
- The animation decide the severity of the stun (how hard it is to get out of stun by mashing buttons). Like: birds require less button pressing than skulls etc.

I have tested this in training mode. I can confirm that the animations are random, because I have stunned Seth with only sweeps for exactly 900 stun points about 20 times in a row and the animations were random.

But I do not know how to check for the stun severity in a similar objective way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after further studies I could not find any indication that the different animations have different effects.

It does not matter either way, as any decent fighter will punish you during the time you are dizzy.

You can shorten the dizzy duration by pressing buttons as fast as you can.